# CSS background with ) in its name?

Tags: html, css

I want to display a div with a background image called something like this:"image_(1)_125x192.jpg". It doesn't display, presumably due to the ")". Is there a way around this without renaming the image?

```
#div {
    background-image: url(image_(1)_125x192.jpg);
    height: 192px;
    width: 125px;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use quotes

```
background-image: url("image_(1)_125x192.jpg");
```

w3 reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-image

Comment: You should get into the habit of using quotes by default. In my experience it saves so much hassle, you know it's *always* going to work.

Comment: Of course, it is possible to create a file with a single quote, a double quote, and a right parenthesis in the name. You would have to hate yourself to do such a thing, but the point I'm trying to make is that Punycode is the way out when nothing else works. It should be avoided, of course, but I thought it was worth pointing out.

Answer (score 5):

```
#div {
    background-image: url('image_(1)_125x192.jpg');
    height: 192px;
    width: 125px;
}
```

note the quote